# How to access a value from outside the ngFor, is it possible?

Tags: angular

```
<table class="table table-sm table-striped table-hover" >
                      <thead class="thead-dark">
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col">#</th>
                          <th scope="col">Nro de Expediente</th>
                          <th scope="col">Causa</th>
                          <th scope="col">Delítos</th>
                          <th scope="col">Última actualización</th>
                          <th scope="col">Estado</th>
                          <th scope="col"></th>
                          <th scope="col"></th>
                          <th scope="col"></th>
                          <th scope="col"></th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let expediente of historial.raexpediente; index as i">
                          <input id="tagcontent" type="hidden"/>
                          <td>{{i+1}}</td>
                          <th scope="row">{{expediente.ranroexpediente}}</th>
                          <td>{{expediente.racausaexpediente}}</td>
                          <td>
                            <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" (click)="open(content,expediente.delitos)">
                              <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
                            </a>
                          </td>           

                          <td>{{expediente.nombreOperacion}}</td>
                          <td>{{expediente.fecha}}</td>
                          <td>
                            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" 
                            routerLink="/movimiento/{{expediente.raidexpediente}}/{{expediente.raidpersona}}">
                              <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
                            </a>
                          </td>                                                                                          

                          <td>
                            <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" 
                            routerLink="/movimiento/{{expediente.raidexpediente}}/{{expediente.raidpersona}}">
                              <i class="fas fa-list-alt"></i>
                            </a>
                          </td>                                                                                          

                          <td>
                            <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" 
                            (click)="openModalMovimientos(movimientosmodal,expediente.movimientos)">Ver</a>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Ver</a>                                                                                                
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>     
                    <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-space" routerLink="/expediente/{{expediente.idpersona}}">Agregar expediente</a>                   
                    <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-space" routerLink="">historial</a>
```

as you can see, in the line

```
<a class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-space" routerLink="/expediente/{{expediente.idpersona}}">Agregar expediente</a>
```

I'am getting an error expediente.idexpediente doesn't have exist, in think this is because expediente.idexpediente is outside of the *ngFor, so well, is there any possibility of getting the expediente.idexpediente in a variable or something?
note: this  is inside an acorrdion and what I do is to loop and fill tables in each accordion

Comment: Is `idpersona` the same value for all the entries in `historial.raexpediente`?

Comment: no, is different per each table and per each person.

Comment: So you have a link out of the loop referring to an `idpersona`.... if they are different, how do you want to choose which one will be in the `routerLink`?